# Framer motion and transform matrix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, framer-motion

I am making app with framer motion and I need to drag svg inside another svg but my problem is that viewbox size is not equal to window size so when I drag element my 1px movement of mouse on the screen is like 100+ px. I know in JavaScript we can calculate x and y with screenX, sceenY and CTM (current transform matrix). Is possible to make somehow framer motion drag function to calculate that?

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 20">
  <motion.circle drag cx="5" cy="5" r="0.5"strokeWidth="0.1"/>
</svg>
```

P.S. I cannot change viewbox size and its 100% of width and height of screen and probably we need to transform current matrix with `useTransform` or `useMotionValue` hooks from framer motion but I am not sure how to do it.

this is current state of the app where you can see the problem when you try to drag player object. https://waterpolo.klaktech.com

Comment: Apparently you don't calculate correctly the mouse position. I suppose ypu calculate the mouse position in pixels (screenX, sceenY) and use the values as svg user units. In this case the width of the svg viewBox is 40 user units. Maybe you should edit your question and show us how do you calculate the mouse position

Comment: @enxaneta I am not calculating anything, I am trying to use framer motion for dragging elements. Do you have any other drag option or custom function to use in react for drag that will work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues understanding properly the question, but I think this is what you were looking for.

There's a couple of catches:

- I am capturing the with and height of each of the boxes to know if they are overlapping at the first useEffect.
- The problem is that when the items change position the REF isn't updated. which means that we need and `onDrag` hook to update the X and Y positions of the boxes.
- The second catch is that the X and Y from there are exposed from the mouse, which means that it's not the one of the origin of the object, so the overlap might not happen till the mouse actually enters the other object

I set this up so you can have a look at the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/paths-forked-0iqtdj?file=/src/Example.tsx

Comment: Can you please look this code and maybe help me to adjust it. Problems are that my constraints are not working as it should and I do not know how to check for overlap, and if that is needed at first place, because I will have more circles imported from different component. Also they just disappear when i try to drag them or when I resize a window. Also I noticed that your viewbox have only 2 parameters 100 100, so probably is not set at all. Should not be 0 0 100 100? codesandbox.io/s/gifted-roman-steszq?file=/src/Player.js